# How to gzip a file while also printing compressed contents to stdout

Tags: linux, pipe, gzip, ksh

i am attempting to compress a series of files in a directory, but also print the contents of the compressed files to stdout.

Given that i have:

```
09:00 /tmp/file1.txt
10:00 /tmp/file2.txt
11:00 /tmp/file3.txt
```

I'm basically looking to perform a `gzip -c /tmp/file?.txt > /tmp/compressed.gz`, but i also want the files to be compressed with keeping the original timestamp:

```
09:00 /tmp/file1.txt.gz
10:00 /tmp/file2.txt.gz
11:00 /tmp/file3.txt.gz
12:00 /tmp/compressed.gz
```

is there any way to do this with one command, and without:

```
for i in $(ls /tmp/file?.txt)
do
      gzip ${i} && cat ${i}.gz >> /tmp/compressed.gz
done
```

I would like to compress and write to disk once, and don't want to hit the disk for the read again.

Comment: You can write to a file and stdout with `gzip .. | tee file.gz`, and you can set timestamps with `touch`.

Comment: gzip works on a single input file so you need to use something like tar to make an archive first. Or just use zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you are asking for in one line:

```sh
ls file*.txt | xargs -n1 -I'{}' bash -c 'cat {} | gzip - | tee {}.gz >> compressed.gz; touch {}.gz -r {}'
```

Each input file is read from disk only once, and the compressed version is saved twice; once in its file*.txt.gz entry, once in the catch-all compressed.gz file. Finally, it adjusts the timestamp of the gzipped file after compression.

Note that this does not delete the original txt file. To remove each file after compressing:

```sh
ls file*.txt | xargs -n1 -I'{}' bash -c 'cat {} | gzip - | tee {}.gz >> compressed.gz; touch {}.gz -r {}; rm {}'
```

Tested on Linux with the GNU versions of `ls`, `xargs`, `bash`, `cat`, `gzip`, `tee`, `touch` and `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested Code**

`gzip` doesn't compress multiple files into one. So you may need a program like `tar` to bundle it first and then compress. There is an option to preserve the access time in tar.

```
gzip file*.txt && tar --atime-preserve=replace -czvf file.tar.gz file*.txt
```